# grant select para view

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Bom dia senhores

eu criei uma view e posteriormente criei um usuário

`CREATE USER pafunsio IDENTIFIED BY "pafunsio";`

atribui o grant para conexão

`GRANT CREATE SESSION TO pafunsio;`

e atribui grant para a view `VW_TEST` que esta no meu schema `teste`

`GRANT SELECT ON  "teste"."VW_TEST" TO "pafunsio";`

porem ao fazer o login com o usuário `pafunsio` não consigo visualizar a view criada
alguém tem alguma ideia do que esta faltando ?

Comment: "visualizar" aonde ? sefor no Developer vai estar em "outros usuários". Consegue executar uma sql como "select * from "teste"."VW_TEST" ?

Comment: com o usuário "SYS" consigo acessar a view sem problema

Comment: qual o problema ? em que programa ?

Comment: eu criei a view com o usuário "SYS", criei a view e atribui os grants, porem quando faço o login com o usuário "pafunsio", e tento fazer um `select * from VW_TEST`, retorna o erro `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: tente select * from SYS.VW_TEST , não se deve criar objetos de usuário no sys ou system

Comment: Funcionou com o select * from teste.VW_TEST, Obrigado Motta